# How to get reference to specific transform in a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab made of three panels, each childed to the one above it. I instantiate the prefab into the scene. I have another script that needs to have a reference to the last panel in that prefab.

I have tried getChild to no success. I'm unsure how I should set:

```
public Transform myPanel;  //(For clarity I should point out that I do not have a reference for myPanel.)
```

to:

```
public Transform theSpecificPanelInThePrefabInstance;
```

Comment: Are there any other children of `myPanel`? Are there any other children of the panel inside `myPanel`? If not, what happens if you try `theSpecificPanelInThePrefabInstance = myPanel.GetChild(0).GetChild(0);`?

Comment: I don't have a reference in myPanel, that is where I am trying to store the reference to theSpecificPanelInThePrefabInstance. There is a child of the panel, but its just another complex set of panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it a little more consistent, add a script to the parent panel with a public Transform reference to the child panel, and assign the reference to the prefab on the inspector.

```
    // Parent.cs
    public Transform grandChild;
```

Then on your script:

```
    // YourScript.cs
    public Transform myPanel;
    Transform theSpecificPanelInThePrefabInstance;
    theSpecificPanelInThePrefabInstance = myPanel.gameObject.GetComponent<Parent>().grandChild;
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but maybe you could clarify something: I make the instance in a different script to the one I need the reference connection. Assuming the instance is stored as ItemPanelWindow in script 1, myPanel is in script 2 and I have created and connected the grandChild as you suggest, what would this look like?

Answer (score 0):

If the field is public, you can set it in the editor. If you need that panel in a more dynamic way, considering adding and querying a [Tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html)